# Bluetooth headset "disconnected"

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I encountered this problem, after installing pulseaudio.

For some reason, I can't connect to my bluetooth headset.
I've tried removing it and pair again, it pairs, then turns "connected" for 1-2 seconds and then "disconnected" again. Any ideas how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution, reinstalling `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` helped!

`sudo apt install --reinstall pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`

Comment: Doesn't work for me